# 2012-09-18 version has no /etc/rc.conf?

Tags: archlinux

I tried archlinux-hf-2012-09-18.img and I notice there is no longer a /etc/rc.conf. I know that ArchLinux switched to systemd but many packages still rely on this old config and, as a result, no longer work. For instance, Avahi :

```
[stephane@alarmpi rc.d]$ sudo /etc/rc.d/avahi-daemon  start
/etc/rc.d/avahi-daemon: line 26: /etc/rc.conf: No such file or directory
/etc/rc.d/avahi-daemon: line 27: /etc/rc.d/functions: No such file or directory
/etc/rc.d/avahi-daemon: line 36: ck_daemon: command not found
/etc/rc.d/avahi-daemon: line 37: stat_busy: command not found
/etc/rc.d/avahi-daemon: line 40: stat_fail: command not found
```

Did I forget something? Or it the archlinux-hf-2012-09-18.img image simply broken?

Answer (score 3):

OK, after discussion on the IRC channel #archlinux-arm, I understand the situation.

Several packages have startup scripts both for the old rc.conf (still documented on the Wiki) *and* for systemd, in a different place (/usr/lib/systemd/system). On a recent ArchLinux, /etc/rc.d scripts must be ignored and daemons are controlled by "systemctl enable $DAEMON.service".

So, there was nothing wrong, just the surprising state of a system which is under transition.

You can have more explanations about the systemd transition in ArchLinux and its reasons: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1149530#p1149530

Comment: The transition is annoying, but the ends will justify the means. Nice job figuring out the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Revert to legacy boot-scripts on the system

```
pacman -S core/initscripts core/sysvinit
```

and remove the `init=/bin/systemd` from `/boot/cmdline.txt`

or

```
systemctl enable avahi-daemon.service
```

as stated [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Daemon#List_of_Daemons).